# Order of the product of two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we have a group $G$ and $H,N \leq G$ such that $HN \leq G$. Then how do I justify the formula: 
$$
|HN| = \frac{|H||N|}{|H\cap N|}
$$

Also, are there any other assumptions neccesary for the formula to hold? Thanks

Comment: You need some assumptions about finiteness, otherwise, division of cardinals is hard to define. (You can also state the result slightly differently and get around this issue, so that it applies to infinite groups. For example, if you write it as $|HN|=|H:H\cap N||N|$, then I think it is still true for infinite groups.) On the other hand, you can drop the assumption that $HN\leq G$, the result is still true without it. (And this question has been asked dozens of time on this website.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If one of the subgroups is normal in $G$, $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$ and you have an exact sequence of group homomorphisms
$$\{1\}\longrightarrow H\cap N\longrightarrow H\times N \longrightarrow HN \longrightarrow \{1\},$$
where the map $H\times N\longrightarrow HN$ is defined by $\;(h,n)\longmapsto hn^{-1}$.

Comment: I am not very good with exact sequences, but are we saying that $(H \times N) / (H \cap N ) \cong HN $ by the first isomorphism theorem and the formula follows? If you could just walk me through what is going on in the exact sequence I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $H$ and $N$ are finite subgroups

We have that $H \cap N \leq H$ and $H \cap N \leq N$

And $|N| = |H \cap N| \cdot [N:H\cap N] \implies [N: H\cap N] = \frac{|N|}{|N\cap H|} \in \mathbb{N}$

So we have that $N = \cup_{i = 1}^{n} H \cap N \cdot c_{i}$ a disjoint union with $c_{i}\in N$ the coclass representative

And we have $H(H\cap N) = H \implies HN = \cup_{i = 1}^{n} H(H\cap N)c_{i} = \cup_{i = 1}^{n} Hc_{i}$ this is a disjoint union too because if $h \in Hc_{i} \cap Hc_{j}$ with $i \not=j$ then $h_{1}c_{i} =h =  h_{2}c_{j}\implies h_{2}^{-1}h_{1} =c_{j}c_{i}^{-1} $ as $h_{2}^{-1}h_{1} \in H$ and $c_{j}c_{i}^{-1} \in N$ then $h_{2}^{-1}h_{1}=c_{j}c_{i}^{-1} \in H\cap N \implies h_{2}^{-1}h_{1}c_{i} = c_{j} \implies c_{j} \in ((H\cap N)c_{j})\cap ((H\cap N)c_{i}) = \emptyset $ this is a contradiction.

Then we have that $|HN| = |H|n = \frac{|H||N|}{|HN|}$